# Update JTable as a window closes

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, windowlistener

Good afternoon!

I have a main program (let's call it window1) that displays a `JTable` and is populated by data in an SQL database. When you double click on the `JTable` it opens up a new window (let's call it window2) that allows the user to edit the database.

I would like to add a `windowListener` to window2 so that as it closes, it tells window1 to repopulate the JTable contained there.

I tried looking around at window events and attempted to figure out how to use them, but I'm just not understanding it... If you need certain parts of my code, feel free to ask.

I have a method in my main program that initially updates the `JTable` when window1 is loaded, but need to figure out how to call that method when window2 closes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I tried looking around at window events and attempted to figure out how to use them, but I'm just not understanding it...` 
Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a WindowListener]() for a working example. However, I don't recommend a WindowListener for this. However, keep the tutorial link handy for this and other Swing basics.

Comment: Moral dialog, modal dialog, modal dialog, any other answer is just wasting time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you have in window2? Any confirmation button maybe? If so, then you could call the JTable's update method inside the listener for that button.

Comment: I do, actually. I have an 'add', 'update', and 'delete' button. I'll try to make that work with the 'update' button. I didn't think about that... Thanks!

Comment: Although this wasn't the answer I was looking for, this solved my problem using an easier way to solve it. So. You are amazing.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to add a windowListener to window2 so that as it closes, it tells window1 to repopulate the JTable contained there.

The difficult part to all this is not the transfer of information -- this can be accomplished simply with getter and setter methods. No the difficulty is usually knowing **when** to transfer the information, and for this you have one of two options.

- The easiest by far is to have window2 to not be a JFrame but to be a **modal** JDialog. This is just like a JFrame and can hold all that a JFrame holds, but will freeze program flow in the main window, until the dialog window is no longer visible. Once this happens, program flow resumes in the main program, and you can query the data held by the dialog window and use the data to update the JTable.
- Another more difficult option is to make window2 a non-modal JDialog, and if you go this route, you'll need to add a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) (please see the link) to it -- I do not recommend this if you can help it.